# data.table row value depend on previous value in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `x`, it has 2 columns `a`, `b`.
I want calculate a `c` column.

```r
library(data.table)

x = data.table(a = c(1:5), b = c(1,0,2,3,6), c = NA)
x$a[1] = NA
x$b[1] = NA

x
#>        a     b      c
#>    <int> <num> <lgcl>
#> 1:    NA    NA     NA
#> 2:     2     0     NA
#> 3:     3     2     NA
#> 4:     4     3     NA
#> 5:     5     6     NA
```

The algorithm is:

```
 c[i] = ifelse(a[i] < b[i] & c[i-1] < b[i], a[i], b[i])
```

I don't want to use for loop, because it's too slow.
I want to use data.table functions, or a fast method like this:

```
x$c = fifelse(x$a < x$b & lag(x$c) < x$b, x$a, x$b)
```

But it's not working, because x$c calculation is in progress right now.
Any solution for this?

Thanks for help
Janos

Comment: What is the expected output? `c[i-1] < b[i]` will alway be NA unless you have a starting value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Reduce` with `accumulate=T` option :

```r
library(data.table)

x = data.table(a = c(1:5), b = c(1,0,2,3,6), c = NA)
x$a[1] = NA
x$b[1] = NA

x[,c:=Reduce(f = function(prev,val) ifelse((val$a < val$b & prev<val$b),val$a,val$b), 
             x = split(.SD[-1],seq_len(.N-1)), init = NA
             ,accumulate = T)][]

#>        a     b     c
#>    <int> <num> <num>
#> 1:    NA    NA    NA
#> 2:     2     0     0
#> 3:     3     2     2
#> 4:     4     3     3
#> 5:     5     6     5
```

`Reduce` passes the result of the previous row calculation to calculate the next row.
`accumulate=T` returns the intermediate results instead of only the last row.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! 
This is too complex for me! :D
And if I have two columns, and the value of "c" depend on "a" and "b" and previous "c"?

Comment: In the `fifelse` example you gave, I didn't see  `b`: could you tell how `b` should be used?

Comment: It's an exact example: 

x = data.table(a = c(1:5), b = c(1,0,2,3,6), c ='')

x$a[1] = NA

x$b[1] = NA

x$c[1] = NA

The calculation should start from the row 2 (first not NA row)!
"c" value should get accoring to this algorithm: 

c[i] = ifelse(a[i] < b[i] & c[i-1] < b[i], a[i], b[i])

Thank you very! :)

Comment: see my edit, this is a bit tricky but seems to work

Comment: Nice, Waldi! I particularly like the use of `x=split(.SD, .N), init=NA` (...) as it's very readable, elegant, and robust.